# How to build and consume gradle plugin inside a multi-module project?

Tags: java, gradle, gradle-plugin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

### The big picture

I have a library which is used as a dependency in other projects. The library has some configuration requirements related to `test suites` for each project depending on it.
This is why I have created a `plugin` that configures those for me so that I could just add the plugin and be done with it:

```
plugins {
   id("org.my.gradle.plugin") version "internal"
}
```

### Project structure

```
+ root
  + my-api/... (self-sustained; doesn't depend on anything, pretty much interfaces)
  + my-implementation/... (depends on my-api and `my-gradle-plugin` via `plugins { id("org.my.plugin") }`)
  + my-gradle-plugin/... (the plugin itself)
    + build.gradle.kts
      plugins {
        `java-gradle-plugin`
        `maven-publish`
      }

      gradlePlugin {
          plugins {
              create("org.my.gradle.plugin") {
                  id = "org.my.gradle.plugin"
                  group = "org.my.gradle.plugin"
                  implementationClass = "org.my.gradle.plugin.MyGradlePlugin"
                  version = project.version
              }
          }
      }


  + build.gradle.kts // a bunch of shared task configurations and some repository configuration (mavenLocal, maven(xyz), mavenCentral())
  + gradle.properties - contains only "version=0.0.3-SNAPSHOT"
  + settings.gradle.kts
    pluginManagement {
        repositories {
            mavenLocal()
            maven { url = uri("https://xyz") }
            gradlePluginPortal()
            mavenCentral()
        }
        resolutionStrategy {
            val version: String by settings
            eachPlugin {
                if (requested.id.id == "org.my.gradle.plugin") {
                    useVersion(version)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

### The problem

The plugin works fine if it's a separate stand alone project. This, unfortunately, complicates my workflow so I thought I could possibly have it within the same multi-module project.

Unfortunately I am running into problems, because `gradle` doesn't seem to know it needs to build the `plugin` in order to `use` it inside one of the modules and therefore I get:

```
* Where:
Build file '/workspace/my-implementation/build.gradle.kts' line: 3

* What went wrong:
Plugin [id: 'org.my.gradle.plugin', version: '0.0.3-SNAPSHOT'] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'org.my.gradle.plugin:org.my.gradle.plugin.gradle.plugin:0.0.3-SNAPSHOT')
  Searched in the following repositories:
    MavenLocal(file:/home/jenkins/.m2/repository/)
    maven(https://xyz)
    Gradle Central Plugin Repository
    MavenRepo
```

### Why does it fail?

I know that [`spring-boot-gralde-plugin`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v3.0.0/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-tools/spring-boot-gradle-plugin/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/gradle/plugin/SpringBootPlugin.java) is part of the spring boot multi-module gradle project and is consumed within the project itself. Unfortunately I haven't been able to figure out what's the "magic trick" to make it work.

Any ideas what I'm missing here?

Comment: You've already figured out the solution, but for reference [here's the relevant bit in the docs](https://docs.gradle.org/7.6/userguide/composite_builds.html#included_plugin_builds).

Answer (score 6):

Well, this took me the better half of the day, but I finally figured it out.

In order to consume the plugin inside the same repository, you must place a `settings.gradle.kts` file inside your `plugin`. This separates the `plugin` build from the rest of your modules. Then you can use `includeBuild()` inside the `pluginManagement` to enforce the building of the plugin before everything else:

```
// ./root/settings.kotlin.kts

rootProject.name = "root-project"

include("my-api", "my-implementation")

pluginManagement {
    includeBuild("my-gradle-plugin")
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven { url = uri("https://xyz") }
        gradlePluginPortal()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    resolutionStrategy {
        val version: String by settings
        eachPlugin {
            if (requested.id.id == "org.my.gradle.plugin") {
                useVersion(version)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can just use the plugin without any issues:

```
plugins {
   id("org.my.gradle.plugin") version "internal"
}
```

I'm using gradle 7.5+ so not sure if this works for older versions.

The docs also mention this here:
https://docs.gradle.org/7.6/userguide/composite_builds.html#included_plugin_builds

Comment: Great answer! I think Stackoverflow needs a "pat yourself on the back button" for this sort of cases where nobody else has even commented, or attempted to help and you end up answering your own complex question.